# How to select a frame using selenium with XPATH?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to fill out various surveys on my university account in an automated way with selenium.

I want to click on the "ESCOLAR" part of the following code snippet:

```
<tbody><tr><td class="title"> MODULO </td></tr>
<tr><td> <img src="/ows-img/closed.gif" alt="ALUMNOS">
               <a href="/wpr/gupmenug.menu?p_sistema_c=ALUMNOS&amp;p_sistemaid_n=4&amp;p_menupredid_n=4&amp;p_pidm_n=425370&amp;p_majr_c=425370" target="Menu">ALUMNOS</a>
               </td></tr>
<tr><td> <img src="/ows-img/closed.gif" alt="ESCOLAR">
          <a href="/wse/gupmenug.menu?p_sistema_c=ESCOLAR&amp;p_sistemaid_n=1&amp;p_menupredid_n=1&amp;p_pidm_n=425370" target="Menu">ESCOLAR</a>
          </td></tr>

</tbody>
```

This is the error that I get:

```
Backtrace:
        Ordinal0 [0x005F6023+2514979]
        Ordinal0 [0x0058F6B1+2094769]
        Ordinal0 [0x004926C8+1058504]
        Ordinal0 [0x004BD2D8+1233624]
        Ordinal0 [0x004BD4CB+1234123]
        Ordinal0 [0x004E7652+1406546]
        Ordinal0 [0x004D635A+1336154]
        Ordinal0 [0x004E59FF+1399295]
        Ordinal0 [0x004D61EB+1335787]
        Ordinal0 [0x004B2617+1189399]
        Ordinal0 [0x004B3479+1193081]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00785624+1579748]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00830417+2279639]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0068473B+527355]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x006837E9+523433]
        Ordinal0 [0x00594BF9+2116601]
        Ordinal0 [0x00599238+2134584]
        Ordinal0 [0x00599372+2134898]
        Ordinal0 [0x005A2EB1+2174641]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76D36359+25]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x774F8944+228]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x774F8914+180]
```

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 3)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='ESCOLAR']"))).click()
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: Does this locator unique? Does this element appears inside a visible screen when you open that page or you have to scroll to it to see it?

Comment: Yes, this locator is unique and this element appears inside a visible screen

Comment: OK. Does it inside some frame? From the HTML piece you shared this can't be seen...

Comment: https://pastebin.com/V1ZKkkE3 This is the code

Comment: I see no frames there...

Comment: So I was wrong :P, with that code, how can I click on "ESCOLAR"?

Comment: It's hard to guess without seeing the web page visually... Maybe instead of `"//a[text()='ESCOLAR']"` try `"//a[contains(text(),'ESCOLAR')]"` ...

Comment: I find the problem: 
`wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"frame[name='Menu']")))`